# read all text files in directory and subdirectories and extract all email addresses from the textfiles

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to extract all email addresses from all text files within a directory with a lot of subdirectories. It is to much work to do this manually. I wrote the python script below to automate this task. However, when I execute the script I end up with an empty array printed. No errors shown. Can one please indicate what I'm doing wrong

```
# Import Module
import os
import re
  
# Folder Path
path = "pat to the root directory"
  
# Change the directory
os.chdir(path)

#create list and index to add the emails
new_list = []
idx = 0

# I create a method to add all email address from within the subdirectories to add 
  them to an array
def read_text_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        emails = re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", str(f))
        new_list.insert(idx, emails)
        idx + 1
     
# iterate through all file and call the method from above
for file in os.listdir():
    # Check whether file is in text format or not
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        p = f"{path}\{file}"
        # call read text file function
        read_text_file(p)

#print the array    
print (new_list)
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to check subdirectories as said you want, you need to check if the current item in the `os.listdir()` list is a folder and if so check all the file in that `folder` (and if there are more folders in that folder check them as well) or a `file` that ends with `.txt`

you also need to `read()` the file (`f.read()`) and only then you can pass it to `re.findall()`

```
# Import Module
import os
import re

# Folder Path
PATH = r"path to folder"  # constants are UPPER CASED LETTERS

# create list to add the emails
new_list = []


def read_text_file(file_path):
    global new_list
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        emails = re.findall(r"[a-z0-9.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", str(f.read()))
        new_list += emails


def find_all_text_files(path):
    # iterate through all file and call the method from above
    path = path if path.endswith("\\") else path + "\\"
    for file_or_dir in os.listdir(path):
        # Check whether file is in text format or not
        if os.path.isfile(path + file_or_dir) and file_or_dir.endswith(".txt"):
            file_path = path + file_or_dir
            # call read text file function
            read_text_file(file_path)
        # if the current item is dir
        elif os.path.isdir(path + file_or_dir):
            new_path = path + file_or_dir
            find_all_text_files(new_path)


def main():
    global new_list
    find_all_text_files(PATH)
    # print the array
    print(new_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This solution worked. Thanks Omar Dagry.

Comment: The only thing I don't understand. Why do you add this at the end of the script:                                                                                                              
if __name__ == '__main__':    main()

Comment: it means that if you import this file the `main()` call won't happen, unless you will call `main()` yourself

Comment: you can look here for more comprehensive explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do-in-python

Comment: and please accept this answer to close this question

Answer (score -1):

When your code doesn't produce expected results, you need to debug it to find the cause. Is it your regex? Is it your `list.insert()`? Is it the conversion of the file handle `f` to a string directly Something else entirely? Let's find out by modifying your `read_text_file()` func to print status:

```
def read_text_file(file_path):
    print(f"attempting to parse {file_path}")
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        huge_line = f.read()
        emails = re.findall(r"[a-z0-9.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", huge_line)
        print(f"found {len(emails)} emails in file {file_path}")
        new_list.extend(emails)
```

I dropped the `idx` var and just used `list.extend()`. Try that out and see where it fails, then add more print statements as needed to narrow it down.

Comment: Need to learn to debug I know. output: attempting to parse filepath - found 0 emails in filepath

Comment: @snorkel I tested my example function above with a short file that contains an email, and it works. The main issue with your original code is that you're converting the filehandle to a string, which results in this string: `'<_io.TextIOWrapper name=\'emails.txt\' mode=\'r\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'>'`

Comment: You're right, the issue is the converting of the file handle to a string which is not correct .Your solution is indeed a working solution when using files under 1 directory. However, I have a lot of subdirectories under the root directory and then this solution will not work. The solution of Omar Dagry will work. Thanks for your help Danielle